Convergence of a product involving primes
Let $p_1, ... , p_n, ...$ be the prime numbers in order. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q_1, ..., q_n \in \mathbb{N}$. Define
$$
P_n = \prod_{k=1}^n p_k^{q_k} \hspace{1cm} Q_n = \prod_{k=1}^n \left( p_k^{q_k} + u_k \right)
$$ where $u_k \in \{-1,+1\}$. Can we prove that if $q_k \geq q$
$$
\frac{P_n}{Q_n} \to^{n\to \infty, q \to \infty} 1 \hspace{1cm}?
$$
For instance if $q_1 = ... = q_n$ and $u_k = -1$ then
$$
\frac{P_n}{Q_n} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 - p_k^{-q}} \to^{n \to \infty} \zeta(q) \to^{q \to \infty} 1
$$ Can some similar result be obtained for the slightly more general case presented above?

Do you know what happens in the case when all the $q_k$ are equal to $q$ but all the $u_k$ are $+1$?

the term in the product is $\frac{p_k^q}{1+p_k^q} = 1 - \frac{1}{p_k^q+1}$ but I do not know where to go from there ...

I am not an analytic number theory guy, so my apologies if I am asking something stupid. First, is it correct that Euler product formula for the zeta function holds whenever the real part of the argument is bigger than $1$? Second, is the convergence of zeta at infinity but off the real line known? E.g. is it true that $\zeta(q+i\pi) \to 1$ as well when $q\to\infty$?

I do not know that for sure at the moment and is late for me to think too deep. A quick look at the first pic in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function (the one with domain coloring) seems to agree to $\zeta(q + i\pi) \to 1$ as well. Do you have an idea?

If both things are true, yes. Note that $\tfrac{1}{1+p_k^{-q}}\leq \tfrac{1}{1+p_k^{-q_k}}\leq \tfrac{1}{1-p_k^{-q_k}}\leq \tfrac{1}{1-p_k^{-q}}$. This means that $\zeta(q+i\pi)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \tfrac{P_n}{Q_n} \leq \zeta(q)$.

Ah sorry, this is not quite correct.  $1+p_k^{-s}$ isn't exactly $1-p_k^{-s+i\pi}$. So this might not be that simple.

Hmm ... $1 - \frac{1}{p^q} \leq 1 - \frac{1}{p^q+1} = \frac{p^q}{1+p^q} = \frac{1}{1 + p^{-q}} \leq  \frac{1}{1 - p^{-q}}$ hene we can obtain $\frac{1}{\zeta(q)} \leq ... \leq \zeta(q)$ right?

Oh, very nice. Didn't think of the $1$ over trick :) I think that settles the question then, right?

Thanks for the chat ... I'll look again tomorrow! It was your work which inspired me! Please have a check your self and write an answer and I'll accept it if it is ok!

Let's look at the reciprocal
$$
\frac{Q_n}{P_n} = \prod_{k=1}^n \biggl( 1 + \frac{u_k}{p^{q_k}} \biggr)
$$
for convenience. If $q>1$ and $q_1,\dots,q_n \ge q$, then
$$
\frac1{\zeta(q)} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \biggl( 1 - \frac{1}{p^q} \biggr) \le \frac{Q_n}{P_n} \le \prod_{k=1}^\infty \biggl( 1 + \frac{1}{p^q} \biggr) = \frac{\zeta(q)}{\zeta(2q)};
$$
therefore $\lim_{q\to\infty} \frac{Q_n}{P_n} = 1$ by the squeeze theorem, uniformly in $n$ and thus regardless of whether $n\to\infty$ or not. A similar proof holds whenever $u_k\in\Bbb C$ is uniformly bounded (as long as we avoid individually vanishing factors).

Very clean way of writing this by taking the reciprocal from the beginning.

Just summarizing the discussion above with the original poster. The solution is virtually theirs.
Claim: Let $p>1$, $a\geq A>0$ such that $p^{-A}\ll 1$ and let $\varepsilon\in\{\pm 1\}$. Then $\tfrac{1}{E(p,A)}\leq \tfrac{1}{1+\varepsilon p^{-a}}\leq E(p,A)$, where $E(p,A)=\tfrac{1}{1-p^{-A}}$.
Proof: This is a simple chain of inequalities. First note that $\tfrac{1}{1+p^{-a}}\leq \tfrac{1}{1+\varepsilon p^{-a}} \leq \tfrac{1}{1-p^{-a}}$.
Now, $\tfrac{1}{\tfrac{1}{1-p^{-A}}}= \tfrac{1}{\tfrac{p^A}{p^A-1}}=1-\tfrac{1}{p^A}\leq 1-\tfrac{1}{p^a}\leq 1-\tfrac{1}{p^a+1}=\tfrac{p^a}{p^a+1}=\tfrac{1}{1+p^{-a}}$, so this proves the left desired inequality.
On the other hand, $\tfrac{1}{1-p^{-a}}\leq \tfrac{1}{1-p^{-A}}$ is equivalent to $1-p^{-A}\leq 1-p^{-a}$, which is equivalent to $p^{-a}\leq p^{-A}$ and $p^A\leq p^a$, which is clearly true. Proof of claim done.
Now, coming back to the problem, it is easy to see that $\tfrac{P_n}{Q_n}=\prod_{k=1}^n \tfrac{1}{1+u_k p_k^{-q_k}}$. We can apply the claim above for each term in the product with $A=q$, $a=q_k$, $p=p_k$ and $\varepsilon=u_k$. This gives us that
\begin{equation}
\tfrac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^n \tfrac{1}{1-p_k^{-q}}}\leq\tfrac{P_n}{Q_n}\leq \prod_{k=1}^n \tfrac{1}{1-p_k^{-q}}
\end{equation}
But note that $\prod_{k=1}^n \tfrac{1}{1-p_k^{-q}}\leq \prod_{k=1}^\infty \tfrac{1}{1-p_k^{-q}}=\zeta(q)$ with the equality being the Euler product formula.
Thus, $\tfrac{1}{\zeta(q)}\leq\tfrac{P_n}{Q_n}\leq \zeta(q)$. As the original poster pointed out, $\lim_{q\to\infty}\zeta(q)=1$ so this proves the desired result by taking the limit as $q\to\infty$.
